# Secure my ExpressJS server Routes, they will accessed through cURLs

Tags: node.js, express, security, curl, request-headers

I'm in need of some advice on what's the best method I can use so that the routes on my server are only accessed by certain users.

My server has some simple routes`"/example"` and I'm using Express JS to write these routes. The people who will access these routes are a few and they will mostly be doing it from terminal with a curl`curl 123.45.678.901/example` but I want to make it secure so that only a certain group of people can access that route.

What should I do? I'm new with this so I was looking into maybe adding a custom header to the curl but I don't know how to check in the route for that custom header and then I thought that might be too simple so I'm wondering if there's a better way that giving the users a "password". Grateful for the advice!

Comment: Is it okay to send a password/secret-key in query parameter? Ex: `localhost/example?key=VERY_SECRET`?

Comment: Honestly, a password would be the way to go. You can check that against a database, or something of the sort. If this is what you decide to go with let me know, I'll submit it as an answer

Comment: You need to require a credential in order to access the route.  The credential can be in the form of a token or password in a custom header, in a query parameter or a token in a cookie.  It's best not to put security credentials in query parameters and obviously, you should be using https to protect the credentials during transport.  If the route is only accessed via CURL, then a custom header containing the credential is probably  the most straightforward way  to do it.

Comment: Inside of express, put all routes that require auth on a specific route and have middleware that verifies the credential before passing control to the routes.

Comment: Hi @Dijkstra, I was looking to prevent creating a DB as this would add too much overhead. I'd rather have them include some unique header or something of the kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require a credential in order to access the protected routes. The credential can be in the form of a token or password in a custom header, in a query parameter or a token in a cookie.

It's best not to put security credentials in query parameters and obviously, you should be using `https` to protect the credentials during transport.

If the route is only accessed via CURL, then a custom header containing the credential is probably the most straightforward way to do it.

For express on your server, put all routes that require auth on a specific router and have middleware that verifies the credential before passing control to the routes.